# Error when react componnent tries to rerender right before the page should switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react app where I switch between two pages (automatic and manual). Each of these two pages shows different data.

First I get from the server list of automatic or manual batches (depending on the pages) and then I make a table for them and for each batch I call the server again to get data of the batch.

So when I call
`"/api/manual/list_batches"`
and I get list of batch names among them for example a batch of name "foo_manual_batch" I can call
`"/api/manual/get_batch?batch_name=foo_manual_batch"`

The problem is that when I switch to the automatic page, I expect it to discard the whole table and call this list_batches again but for automatic:
`"/api/automatic/list_batches"` and then call `"api/automatic/get_batch?batch_name=..."` for every new batch name.

However what happens is that right before the new list of batches is obtained, The table sees that the "mode" variable obtained from the URL has changed from manual to automatic and tries to rerender the rows by calling `"/api/automatic/get_batch?batch_name=foo_manual_batch"` which gives an error.

The page works fine, but there are these unnecessary server calls happening on switching between automatic and manual and I struggle few days to find how to fix it.

Here I created a minimal working example where you can see the error logs while switching between automatic and manual indicating the unwanted api calls.

App

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import BatchesPage from "./BatchesPage";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Navigation />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/:mode">
          <Navigation />
          <BatchesPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

BatchesPage

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import BatchesTable from "./BatchesTable";
import { fetchJson } from "./model";

export default function BatchesPage() {
  const [batchesNames, setBatchesNames] = useState([]);
  const { mode } = useParams();
  const getBatchesNamesCmd = `/api/${mode}/list_batches`;

  // loads automatic batches names or manual batches names depending on the mode
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJson(getBatchesNamesCmd)
      .then((jsonData) => {
        setBatchesNames(jsonData.sort().reverse());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`error occure: ${error}`);
      });
  }, [getBatchesNamesCmd]);

  return batchesNames ? (
    <div>
      {mode === "automatic" ? (
        <div className="horizontal-container">
          {["fruit", "vegetable"].map((keyword) => (
            <BatchesTable
              key={keyword}
              batchesNames={batchesNames.filter((name) =>
                name.includes(keyword)
              )}
              viewMode="narrow"
              tableName={keyword}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <BatchesTable batchesNames={batchesNames} viewMode="wide" />
      )}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-carson-qiwv7d

Can you please help me to figure out how to write the react components correctly so that this issue is not happening?

Comment: My approach would be, to use a reducer (you can use redux or useReducer hook) , so i can have the data in a global state. then inside the useEffect i will add an if statement to check if this name exist in the global state. if not, fetch. the reducer can be an object with key as the name so you can check in the if statement if state.key === batchName. (you can also have the state in the parent component.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a race condition between the route path changing, e.g. the mode from `"automatic"` to `"manual"` and vice versa, and what the current value of the `batchesNames` in `BatchesPage` and the `batch` in `BatchRow` states prior to them being updated.

You *could* go through all the components and check their lifecycle effects and try to reset these state values back to their initial state values, but then there's an issue between React state updates being processed asynchronously and the JSON data fetch immediately happening.

A super trivial solution is to completely remount a new instance of the `BatchesPage` component when the route path changes. Use the `mode` route path parameter as a React key.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/:mode"
          render={({ match }) => <BatchesPage key={match.params.mode} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit error-when-react-componnent-tries-to-rerender-right-before-the-page-should-switc]

Comment: Completely remounting a new instance of the `BatchesPage` according to the given example solved my issue :)